# Move files to S3 then remove source files after completion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am just familiarising myself with Amazon Web Services and S3 AWS CLI.

Does anyone know if it's possible to remove files from the source that exist on the destination bucket?

I was trying the below:

```
aws s3 sync /home/recsout s3://myfakebucketname001 --delete
```

I was previously using rsync to a NAS drive with `--remove-source-files` but want to use S3 and AWS CLI instead.

Comment: I answered my own question there is a mv command                            aws s3 mv /home/recsout s3://myfakebucketname001 --recursive

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `aws s3 sync` command in the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is used to synchronize the source to the target. **It does not delete files from the *source* after copying.** However, the `--delete` option will remove files from the *target* if they are not present in the source (thereby making the target truly match the source).

If your intent is to **copy a file and then remove it**, use the `aws s3 mv` command, which copies it and then removes it from the source.

Also, it's worth mentioning that the `aws s3` commands can work from a local disk to an Amazon S3 bucket, or from an S3 bucket to a local disk, or even between two S3 buckets.

Answer (score 0):

aws s3 mv command seem to be the solution.

```
$ aws s3 mv <source> <target> [--options]

$ aws s3 mv s3://bucket-name/example s3://my-bucket/

$ aws s3 mv filename.txt s3://bucket-name

$ aws s3 mv s3://bucket-name/filename.txt ./
```

more info:[Official Documentation: AWS S3 MV](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-s3-commands.html#:%7E:text=s3%20rm%20examples-,Move%20objects,-Use%20the%20s3)